# Android black box testing tool

Tags: android, functional-testing, black-box-testing

I am searching for a tool/software for black box testing of android apps. I researched for some of them-Robotium, Calabash. But these tools require access to the source codes.
Also the tool should be free and opensource for use.

Comment: Isn't Robotium OS and from what i know doesn't require access to the source code?

Comment: A new android UI testing tool is repeato. It does not require access to the source code and works based on computer vision: https://www.repeato.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [Calabash-Android](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android). It does not need access to source code and you can use it with a signed .apk file. You would only need to know the id of the UI elements if you want to manipulate them.

Answer (score 4):

The Android SDK itself offers:

- the [Test Monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html)
- [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)
- [UIAutomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)